# Exterior Measure and Non-Measurable Sets

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory

Can you help me to prove that a set $E\subset\mathbb{R}$ has non-measurable subsets (Lebesgue Measure) if and only if $m^{*}(E)>0$ ?

Somehow i couldn't generalize Vitali Set to prove $\Leftarrow$ direction. The other direction is not a problem !

Thank you :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this instead.  Take a Bernstein set $B$ (a set that has nonempty intersection with every uncountable closed set and whose complement also has nonempty intersection with every uncountable closed set) in $\mathbb R$.  Both $B$ and its complement $B^c$ are Bernstein sets, and at least one exists (this was shown by Bernstein).

Take $E \cap B$.  Then every uncountable closed subset of $E$ meets $E \cap B^c$ at some point.  Take any measurable subset $A \subset E \cap B$.  Any closed set contained in $A$ must be countable.  So $A$ must have measure $0$.  In particular, if $E \cap B$ is measurable, then it has measure $0$.  We can repeat the argument for $E \cap B^c$.

But if $E \cap B$ and $E \cap B^c$ are both measurable, then their union is measurable and must thus have measure $0$, a contradiction.

Comment: Wow, cool argument. I didn't know about the existence of Bernstein Sets. Thank you so much :)

Comment: @thetruth Yeah, the Bernstein argument is interesting because it relies on topological notions (closed sets) instead of translation invariance.